# Is it possible to alter an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

Is this possible? Say you have the following:

```
var x = new { name = "name", age = 22 };
```

Is it possible to then add or append a property to this object? So at a later stage I could add height to make it `{ name = "name", age = 22, height = 1.9 };`.

It doesn't have to be elegant just looking for a way to recast or something to add in a new property.

Comment: Are you .NET 4? Sounds like you want a dynamic type, not an anonymous one.

Comment: var y = new { x.name, x.age, height = 1.9 };

Comment: Might want to see [add-properties-to-an-object-with-reflection-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312276/add-properties-to-an-object-with-reflection-in-c?lq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is absolutely not possible. Anonymous types are immutable, and defined exactly by the names and types of their properties and the order that they appear. Adding a new property is a  different type.

The best that you can do within anonymous types is create an instance of a **different** anonymous type:

```
var y = new { name = x.name, age = x.age, height = 1.9 };
```

(Note that the `name =` and `age =` are not necessary; the compiler will infer them for you.)

But really it sounds like you want either `dynamic`, or a property bag like a `Dictionary<string, object>` if you're not in .NET 4.0.

Or maybe, just maybe, a concrete type like this:

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public decimal? Height { get; set; }
}
```

Note that `height` is nullable.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a new anonymous type?

```
var x = new { name = "name", age = 22 };
var y = new { x.name, x.age, height = 1.9 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) could be usable?

```
dynamic x = new ExpandoObject();
x.name = "name";
x.age = "22";
x.height = 1.9;
```