# Add properties to an object with reflection in c #

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I would like to create a method that receive 3 strings as parameter and return an object that contains three properties that they referred to these Strings.

Do not have an "old Object" to replicate. The properties should be created in this method.

Is to do this in C # with reflection? If so, how? Below is what you like and I am not able to do.

```
protected Object getNewObject(String name, String phone, String email)
{
    Object newObject = new Object();

    ... //I can not add the variables that received by the object parameter here.

    return newObject();
}
```

Comment: How would you then be *accessing* those properties? DynamicObject is probably the closest you can come to this easily, in terms of dynamic access. We really need more context though.

Comment: Taken from where these properties? Where is the "oldObject"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete example using Expando object is like this

```
protected dynamic getNewObject(String name, String phone, String email)
    {


        // ... //I can not add the variables that received by the object parameter here.
        dynamic ex = new ExpandoObject();
        ex.Name = name;
        ex.Phone = phone;
        ex.Email = email;
        return ex;
    }

    private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ye = getNewObject("1", "2", "3");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name = {0},Phone = {1},Email={2}", ye.Name, ye.Phone, ye.Email));
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add properties, fields etc. in dynamic, you may try using *Expando* class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx

```
 dynamic newObject = new ExpandoObject();

 newObject.name = name;
 newObject.phone = phone; 
 newObject.email = email
```

Answer (score 4):

```
protected dynamic getNewObject(String name, String phone, String email)
{
    return new { name = name, phone = phone, email = email };
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter Why is this not good? Seems like the correct answer.

Comment: It is the correct answer. Adding properties with reflection is not the solution, he will not be able to access them later without reflection. And if that is the case, why not just create a class? Might as well go with `dynamic`.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but technically it should be: return new { name = GetWithReflectionTheNameOfSomething(), phone = GetWith...(), email = GetWith...() };

Comment: Unless he really wanted an anonymouse object with a property named `name` with the string of the `name` parameter.

Comment: Anonymous types are only usable inside the same method. Consuming the result of this will be possible but very awkward (everything through reflection). [OK, after adding the return dynamic it seems OK]

Comment: @xanatos Yeah, but that would not be very refactor-friendly. If he was to change the name of the parameters in `getNewObject`, the rest of his application would break when he was using the return value of it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I always thought it was soo much easy to use anonymous types :-) http://ideone.com/mIswW5